Planet with minimal atmosphere and solid surface
I know it's not possible to have liquid exposed to vacuum without freezing or vaporizing.
Talking about a planet, with similar gravity to that of Earth, with no land emerging from an all-encompassing water sea (with arguable ice layer).
I'm looking for the best balance so that there is the least atmosphere possible, while having the ice layer (if any) be the as thin as possible. The idea is that a vehicle/rocket going from the planet to space cannot start on a solid surface and spends the least time in atmosphere as possible. What conditions on the atmosphere composition, distance to star (and nature of star), possibly ocean composition would optimize that, and what could be the result on atmosphere properties and ice layer thickness ?

By definition liquids cannot sublimate.

Man, I get what you're saying, but there are some mistakes with basic concepts. Liquids can’t sublimate; they boil. Only solids can sublimate because sublimation is defined as the transition from solid to gas without passing through a liquid phase.

Some liquids (e.g. mercury, glycerol, and many ionic liquids https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_liquid) have extremely low vapor pressures, and thus really can be exposed to vacuum without boiling (much). None that you're likely to find an ocean of, though.

@SomeoneElse37 right, and I do want it to be a water ocean (possibly ionized but that's it). I'll make it clearer in the question.

Does salty mud count as an ocean?

Once you get to the stage of rocket building, you should be able to form an ice patch or sufficiently large buoyant platform that mostly negates any of your "liquid surface" difficulties.

Looking into the moon Europa is likely a great start. Having a liquid water layer, beneath a layers of ice.

Water (only if not salt soved) can be liquid, solid, or gaseous depending on two factors: temperature and pressure.
Fortunately for you, the requirement is simple to meet. At any temperature below 0 °C, water is solid. At any pressure lower than 0.006 atm, water exists as vapor. At exactly 0.006 atm and 0.01 °C, you reach the triple point where water simultaneously evaporates, melts, and freezes (it’s solid, liquid, and gas all at once — it’s truly fascinating to see in person).
Therefore, your planet would need a pressure and temperature that fall within the range of the phase diagram corresponding to liquid water, such as 0.007 atm at 0.07 °C.
It’s also worth noting that, just as water can be at its triple point, it can exist somewhere between its saturated states. For example, at 1 atm and 100 °C, water begins to boil but does not instantly transition from liquid to gas; instead, a mixture is produced. Here, the concept of vapor quality is relevant, as it indicates, for a given pressure-temperature pair and the substance's enthalpy at that moment, the percentage that is vapor. (Anything between saturated vapor and saturated liquid is possible).


Sure, but that can't be achieved at the whole surface of the planet, no planet is entirely at the same temperature. If that temperature is reached at the equator, there would be polar ice caps. If it is reached at the poles, the equator would be much hotter, which would... raise the atmo pressure there ? not sure.

@Gouvernathor You will be right if it were not for the margins, ultimately in an atmosphere water can be liquid between 1 and 99 °C, at 1 atm, in 0.007 atm your margin would be approximately between 0.07 and 0.1 °C

As the pressure goes down, so does the boiling point. Liquids cannot exist under a vacuum, because under a vacuum the liquid will boil at any temperature.
On the other hand, the freezing point is just about the same under a pressure of 1 atmosphere or under a vacuum. What happens is that under very low pressure, the liquid will start boiling off; this will cool the liquid, and in a short time the remaining liquid will freeze.
There is an unhappy wrinkle in this: water ice sublimates very easily at anything resembling normal temperatures. This is why you can hang your laundry out to dry even in freezing (but dry) weather. And it sublimates even easier at anything resembling normal tempeatures under very low pressure. This will further cool down the ocean, and the ice layer will grow. I just don't see how you could have very low atmospheric pressure and a thin ice layer at the same time.

There are a few more conclusions one can draw from the nice graphic in darth momins answer. If we want liquid water at low pressure, the temperature range on the planet needs to be very small, meaning the temperature is roughly constant all over the planet and there is little temperature change over the year and in the day/ night cycle.
Low temperature differential in the day/ night cycle is easiest by having a very short cycle, meaning a high rotational speed. Small seasonal variation is best achieved by having zero inclination of the planetary axis of rotation so there is no polar winter/ summer. The distance to and nature of the star can then be chosen so that the average temperature is just slightly above 0°C. Athmospheric pressure should be a little over 0.006 atm.
Having major currents in your ocean to even out any temperature differences should also help.

I figured you could use some sort of Biological Goo that floats on top of the ocean and prevents it from evaporating while providing enough pressure to keep it from boiling, like a bacterial film or an algae layer or something. There wouldn't need to be any atmosphere to speak of, and the Goo wouldn't be anywhere near solid enough to support a rocket before it sank through the Goo into the ocean. Presumably the Goo would just gloop over any holes that a rocket made in the surface. If you had something like this, you'd have a lot more leeway in placing your planet in a realistic orbit around a star.
So I ran the numbers to see what that would look like. Turns out it's not easy but not impossible. These numbers would work for an ice layer too, but I don't know how easily the ice could fill in holes made by a meteor or a rocket, or how the ice would stay thin but not too thin over geological time scales or over the full surface of the planet.
If the Goo floats on the ocean, it must be less dense than water. Let's assume this Goo is only a tiny bit less dense than water. Water (and therefore Goo) has a density of 0.036 lb/in³, which means that you'll need a layer of Goo that's just under 28 inches thick if you want 1 PSI of pressure on the surface of the ocean. You can double that for 2 PSI, etc.
At about 0.1 PSI (roughly 0.006 atm, also roughly the atmospheric pressure at the surface of Mars), the boiling point of water is only a tiny bit above the freezing point of water. That translates to about a 2.8" thick layer of Goo, but you won't have much of a temperature range at all between boiling and freezing. If we double the Goo to 5.6" thick, that's 0.2 PSI which puts the boiling point at 53°F. A foot of Goo will give you a boiling point of 75°F.
The hottest recorded ocean temperature on Earth was about 100°F, which would be a boiling temperature at roughly 1 PSI, or almost two and a half feet of Goo. But those high temperatures are likely partially due to having a thin layer of water above a landmass that gets heated by the Sun. If you had a glossy, reflective sort of Goo that doesn't heat easily, and if you had open, circulating water underneath it, you likely wouldn't reach anywhere near those 100° temperatures and you could get away with less Goo.
Another way to get away with less Goo would be to mix antifreeze chemicals into your water. Ethylene glycol, the chemical in commercial automobile antifreeze, actually raises the boiling point of water and lowers its freezing point. So if your ocean had ethylene glycol or any similar chemicals in it, even if only in the upper layers, your ocean could remain liquid below 32°F and have a thinner layer of Goo capping it. Ethylene glycol has been found in space, although I suspect you'd need some sort of biological source if you wanted enough to significantly lower the boiling point of a planet's worth of ocean.
For my calculations of boiling temperature at low pressures, I used https://www.shipcopumps.com/tools/mathwizard/index.php?category=npsh&id=boiling-points - they build water pumps so they've likely included low pressures in their calculations.

Basically Europa

Credit: NASA/JPL-Caltech
Solid surface? Check:
Europa has a surface of about 3-30km thick ice. I would call that quite solid.
Minimal atmosphere? Check:

Surface pressure 0.1 μPa (10^−12 bar)
-wiki

Liquid sea? Check
Europa has more than 2x the amount of water the Earth has spread out over a much smaller surface.
Earth gravity? No go...
Sadly, Europa isn't perfect for this question. Yet. At 1/4 the diameter, Europa is quite a bit smaller. This impacts the gravity quite a bit. At 0.134g. Enlarging Europa will change the gravity, which will also make it better at holding an atmosphere. I expect the layer of ice to thin a small amount with a thicker atmosphere, because the extra weight should compress the lowest layer of ice back into water.
Take-offs in this atmosphere should be a challenge. Trying to take off an ice sheet, which both freezes to your rocket legs and melt the surface underneath the rocket on takeoff. While contending with extremely cold temperatures, and geysers could form under the rocket.
Escape velocity is quite a bit lower (2.025km/s), at its current small size, but will increase if you decide to size Europa up. And with next to no atmosphere, you would leave said atmosphere very quickly.
